# "These ones... Those ones..."-Are those phrases correct?

Tags: speech, demonstratives

I was at my house and my mom asked me to get chips. I got the chips and said

> These ones?

Then my mom said "yes" and then my dad said "It's best to just say ***these***". Was my statement correct?

Comment: *These* = the ones over here. Do we want the ones over here ones?

Comment: We can put in or leave out 'ones' after 'these' and 'those' - these (ones), those (ones)

Answer (score 2):

You were utterly correct. If you just say *these?*, that would be the use of *these* as a determinative in a fused Determiner-Head construction. If, on the other hand, you say *these ones*,  that would be a canonical noun phrase with a determinative in Determiner function, and the common noun *one(s)* as a nominal phrase functioning as Head within the larger NP (noun phrase).

Both are grammatical in standard English. For further information consult *The Cambridge Grammar of the English language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/616793/2085).

Answer (score 0):

An answer from a web site:

https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/25/these-ones/

> these ones

> By itself, there’s nothing wrong with the word “ones” as a plural: “surrounded by her loved ones.” However, “this one” should not be pluralized to “these ones.” Just say “these.”

The author, a retired professor of literature, deals with the question of what is an error (thus, presumably, not correct) as follows:

> What is an error in English?

> The concept of language errors is a fuzzy one. I’ll leave to linguists the technical definitions. Here we’re concerned only with deviations from the standard use of English as judged by sophisticated users such as professional writers, editors, teachers, and literate executives and personnel officers. The aim of this site is to help you avoid low grades, lost employment opportunities, lost business, and titters of amusement at the way you write or speak.

Comment: But is "these ones" correct?

Comment: No, it’s not correct. It’s non-standard English.

Comment: It's redundant and not idiomatic.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Utter rubbish. Sorry, but there's nothing to to say that *these ones* is incorrect at all. Look in any vetted academic grammar of English. Literature professors may or may not be experts in syntax, or in the use of standard English.

Comment: Several thousand hits in the NOW (News on the Web) corpus would disagree with the claim that 'these ones' is non-standard English, or incorrect English. At best, we could say it's stylistically undesirable according to some.

Answer (score 0):

*These/those ones* may sound informal, it may sound redundant (though I beg to differ, at least in some contexts), but it is definitely not incorrect.

[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/08/these-ones.html) gets thumbs up from me for its articles about the matter, because though it acknowledges their own dislike of the usage of this phrase, it nevertheless gives clear evidence of its legitimacy:

> As we said then, we don’t like this usage. But we could find no authoritative evidence against it, and on the contrary there was reliable evidence in its favor.
>
> The linguist Nicholas Widdows reports finding examples in the British National Corpus of “these” and “these ones” used in different senses. Here’s how he explains the difference:
>
> > Faced with an array of jelly babies I might point to a red one and say, ‘I like ***these ones***.’  The fused head [plain *these*] could be misinterpreted as referring to all jelly babies; ***the ‘ones’ says more clearly ‘this type.’***

Exactly my point, ***ones*** is not always redundant. You can sense that *these/those* can be more general than *these/those (particular) ones* in certain contexts.

The same article states:

> ***The fact that we dislike a usage doesn’t make it incorrect.*** Nor does
> the fact that some online language junkies claim it’s wrong, without
> offering any evidence to support their opinions.
>
> You argue that “ones” is redundant in “these ones,” but do you really
> find “one” redundant in the phrases “this one” and “that one” for the
> same reason?
>
> And what about if we add a modifier to “these ones” or “those ones”?
> Would you object to “these heavy ones,” “those black ones,” and so on?

I would add to this, that if ***the** black ones* is fine, who's to say that ***these/those** black ones* is not? Also if *this* means *the one over here*, then is *here* redundant in

> ***Shall I use this knife here*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/this-that-these-those))?

As a reliable source, *Grammarphobia* quotes the *Cambridge History of the English Language*, which

> indicates that “ones” here is an anaphoric pronoun—a pronoun that refers back to another word or phrase. In this case the pronoun is preceded by a determiner, a modifier like “these” or “those.”
>
> Cambridge says “those ones” first showed up in the 19th century, and “these ones” in the 20th. However, we’ve found many formal and informal examples of “those ones” going back to the 1600s, and of “these ones” dating from the 1700s.

So there you go, you can use this phrase with a clean conscience, just be aware that you might displease some. I don't see the point in correcting what you said, especially that this is an informal conversation. In writing, adding an adjective between *these/those* and *ones* might render the phrase stylistically more acceptable. But I find it used even on its own in plenty of official texts. If you read on this article from Grammarphobia, you will find some good examples.